# exporting html to excel local image is not showing in excel

Tags: javascript, html, css, excel

I am working with exporting html to excel.All my content is rendering except Image. my image is in  base 64 format . even though if i keep google image height and width is not applying but rendering the image ? is there any way to render local image to excel and apply styles.
here is my script code

```js
var uri = 'data:application/vnd.ms-excel;base64,',
 template = '<html xmlns:o="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:office" xmlns:x="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:excel" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/TR/REC-html40"><head><meta http-equiv="content-type" content=""text/html; charset=windows-1252"/><!--[if gte mso 9]><xml><x:ExcelWorkbook><x:ExcelWorksheets><x:ExcelWorksheet><x:Name>{worksheet}</x:Name><x:WorksheetOptions><x:DoNotDisplayGridlines/></x:WorksheetOptions></x:ExcelWorksheet></x:ExcelWorksheets></x:ExcelWorkbook></xml><![endif]--></head><body><table>{table}</table></body></html>',
 base64 = function(s) {
  return window.btoa(unescape(encodeURIComponent(s)))
 },
 format = function(s, c) {
  return s.replace(/{(\w+)}/g, function(m, p) {
   return c[p];
  })
 }
var ctx = {
 worksheet: 'Worksheet',
 table: table.innerHTML
}
uri = uri + base64(format(template, ctx));

var dlink = document.createElement('a');
dlink.href = uri;
dlink.download = 'test';
dlink.click();
```

Comment: Please reformat your code here. Its not helpful in this case anyway.

Comment: Did you ever figure this out? I'm running into the same issue where the icons are displaying as red Xs instead of images.